kubuntu 24.04 installer stuck at kubuntu-installer-prompt (& wont boot beyond password prompt!)
Kubuntu 22.04 started showing serious quircks in it's visual display (combining the variety background switcher with plasma semi-transparent windows), so i thought today would be a good day to upgrade.
But the installer is stuck at displaying the grey background of kubuntu-installer-prompt (until you let the thing go into screensaver mode), and after installation (tried a minimal install first) i'm also unable to login beyond the password prompt - the thing is stuck on loading the settings for the desktop.
I'm trying a full install now, see if that helps.
I'd like to help the Kubuntu community sort this out :)
Feel free to ask me for system details.
EDIT : full install -> same results after logging in :(

UPDATE : i can login if i first boot into recovery mode, open up a commandline prompt and exit it to resume normal booting ;)

Your details are somewhat unclear; the kubuntu-installer-prompt is run only on live media, not an installed system.  You also mention variety which is a GTK3 program & thus not used by Kubuntu (KDE Plasma or a Qt5 desktop) and not found on install media where kubuntu-installer-prompt is found. If you installed, your issue is likely graphics/kernel module related, thus have you installed any?  ubuntu-drivers autoinstall for example??  but that is done post-install & not whilst using live media (where kubuntu-installer-prompt is used).

hi guiverc, the kbuntu-installer-prompt mishap happened with a live .iso for 24.04 near the end of May(!).. and i dunno how i installed variety, but i do think this functionality should be included in some future version of KDE plasma, if that's what the kubuntu folks intend to stick with.
and i installed the nvidia graphics drivers directly from their website.
